# Hilbert transform of unit step function

Tags: fourier-transform, fourier, hilbert-transform

How to calculate Hilbert transform, if it exists, of the signals like $u(t)$, $sgn(t)$.

What properties should a function satisfy for existence of Hilbert transform.

Absolute integrability of a signal $x(t)$ is necessary condition for HT to exist?

Comment: Have you tried searching the web? I see many relevant results with a simple google search. eg. http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/247a.1.06f/notes4.pdf and also see Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform#Domain_of_definition

Answer (score 3):

Absolute integrability is not a necessary condition for the Hilbert transform to exist. Simple counterexamples are the Hilbert transforms of $\cos(\omega t)$ and $\sin(\omega t)$, given by $\sin(\omega t)$ and $-\cos(\omega t)$, respectively, if $\omega>0$.

Since the functions $u(t)$ and $\textrm{sgn}(t)$ are related by scaling and an additive constant, and since the Hilbert transform of a constant is zero, the Hilbert transforms of the two functions - if they exist - must be scaled versions of each other:

$$\textrm{sgn}(t)=2u(t)-1\\\Rightarrow \mathcal{H}\{\textrm{sgn}(t)\}=2\mathcal{H}\{u(t)\}\tag{1}$$

I believe that the Hilbert transform of these two functions can be computed in the following way. [Edit: this turned out to be true. See below and the comments to [RBJ's answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/49056/4298).] We know that the Hilbert transform can be written as a convolution:

$$\mathcal{H}\{x(t)\}=\frac{1}{\pi t}\star x(t)\tag{2}$$

This can be rewritten as

$$\mathcal{H}\{x(t)\}=\frac{1}{\pi}\left(\log(|t|)\right)'\star x(t)=\frac{1}{\pi}\log(|t|)\star x'(t)\tag{3}$$

where $'$ denotes differentiation w.r.t. $t$. The rightmost equality in $(3)$ is true because we generally have

$$(f\star g)'=f'\star g=f\star g'\tag{4}$$

With $x(t)=u(t)$ we get $x'(t)=\delta(t)$, and from $(3)$ we obtain

$$\mathcal{H}\{u(t)\}=\frac{1}{\pi}\log(|t|)\star \delta(t)=\frac{1}{\pi}\log(|t|)\tag{5}$$

From $(1)$ and $(5)$ we get

$$\mathcal{H}\{\textrm{sgn}(t)\}=\frac{2}{\pi}\log(|t|)\tag{6}$$

---

The results given by Eqs $(5)$ and $(6)$ can also be derived in the frequency domain. The Fourier transform of the convolution

$$\mathcal{H}\{u(t)\}=\frac{1}{\pi t}\star u(t)$$

is given by

$$\mathcal{F}\left\{\frac{1}{\pi t}\right\}\mathcal{F}\{u(t)\}=-j\;\textrm{sgn}\{\omega\}\left(\pi\delta(\omega)+\frac{1}{j\omega}\right)=-\frac{\textrm{sgn}(\omega)}{\omega}=-\frac{1}{|\omega|}$$

So we have

$$\mathcal{H}\{u(t)\}=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left\{-\frac{1}{|\omega|}\right\}$$

From [this document](http://www.oulu.fi/sites/default/files/content/files/fourier.pdf) (p. 27, Ex. 19.4), we know that

$$\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left\{-\frac{1}{|\omega|}\right\}=\frac{1}{\pi}\log(|t|)$$

confirming Eq. $(5)$.

(Note the different scaling in the cited document due to the use of the unitary Fourier transform.)

---

EDIT:

The problem can also be solved using the definition of the [Hilbert transform of bounded functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform#Hilbert_transform_of_bounded_functions):

$$\mathcal{H}\{f(t)\}=\frac{1}{\pi}\left[\mathrm{p.v.}\int_{|\tau|<1}\frac{f(\tau)}{t-\tau}d\tau+\mathrm{p.v.}\int_{|\tau|>1}f(\tau)\left(\frac{1}{t-\tau}+\frac{1}{\tau}\right)d\tau\right]$$

where $\mathrm{p.v.}$ denotes the [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value).

For $f(t)=u(t)$ we have

$$\mathcal{H}\{u(t)\}=\frac{1}{\pi}\left[\underbrace{\mathrm{p.v.}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{d\tau}{t-\tau}}_{\displaystyle I_1}+\underbrace{\mathrm{p.v.}\int_{1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{t-\tau}+\frac{1}{\tau}\right)d\tau}_{\displaystyle I_2}\right]$$

If $t$ is outside the interval $(0,1)$, the first integral is simply

$$I_1=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{d\tau}{t-\tau}=\log\left(\frac{t}{t-1}\right)$$

If $t\in (0,1)$ we get

$$I_1=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_0^{t-\epsilon}\frac{d\tau}{t-\tau}+\int_{t+\epsilon}^1\frac{d\tau}{t-\tau}=\log\left(\frac{t}{\epsilon}\right)+\log\left(\frac{-\epsilon}{t-1}\right)=\log\left(\frac{t}{1-t}\right)$$

Since in both cases the argument of the logarithm is positive, both results can be summarized as

$$I_1=\log\left|\frac{t}{1-t}\right|$$

If $t<1$ the second integral is

$$I_2=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\left[\int_1^{1/\epsilon}\frac{d\tau}{t-\tau}+\int_1^{1/\epsilon}\frac{d\tau}{\tau}\right]=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\left[\log\left(\frac{t-1}{t-1/\epsilon}\right)+\log\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right)\right]=\\=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\log\left(\frac{t-1}{\epsilon t-1}\right)=\log\left(1-t\right)$$

If $t>1$ we have

$$I_2=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\left[\int_1^{t-\epsilon}\frac{d\tau}{t-\tau}+\int_{t+\epsilon}^{1/\epsilon}\frac{d\tau}{t-\tau}+\int_1^{1/\epsilon}\frac{d\tau}{\tau}\right]=\\=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\left[\log\left(\frac{t-1}{\epsilon}\right)+\log\left(\frac{-\epsilon}{t-1/\epsilon}\right)+\log\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right)\right]=\\=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\log\left(\frac{1-t}{\epsilon t-1}\right)=\log(t-1)$$

Again, both results can be summarized as

$$I_2=\log|1-t|$$

Combining these results, we obtain the Hilbert transform of $u(t)$:

$$\mathcal{H}\{u(t)\}=\frac{1}{\pi}(I_1+I_2)=\frac{1}{\pi}\left(\log\left|\frac{t}{1-t}\right|+\log|1-t|\right)=\frac{1}{\pi}\log|t|$$

which agrees with our previous result given by Eq. $(5)$.

Comment: another way to do it is with the integral definition of the convolution and identifying cancelled parts of that improper integral and leaving a finite result.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Would be great if you provided an answer with an alternative derivation using integrals.

Comment: not great, Matt.  see if you can figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

To integrate the convolution integral of the Hilbert transform, one must make use of the concept of the [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) (p.v.) of an integral with some kinda nasty infinity or singularity in it.

Hilbert Transform:

$$\begin{align}
\hat{x}(t) &\triangleq \mathscr{H}\Big\{ x(t) \Big\} \triangleq \frac{1}{\pi t} \ \circledast x(t) \\
\\
 &= \mathrm{p.v.} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\pi v} \ x(t-v) \mathrm{d}v \\
\\
 &= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int\limits_{-1/\epsilon}^{-\epsilon} \frac{1}{\pi v} \ x(t-v) \mathrm{d}v \ + \ \int\limits_{\epsilon}^{1/\epsilon} \frac{1}{\pi v} \ x(t-v) \mathrm{d}v \\
\end{align}$$

That's in general.  Now let $x(t)$ be the unit step function (i will leave the symbol "$u$" be used for something else):

$$ x(t) = \tfrac{1}{2}\big(1 + \operatorname{sgn}(t)\big) = \begin{cases}
0 \qquad & t<0 \\
\tfrac12 \qquad & t=0 \\
1 \qquad & t>0 \\
\end{cases} $$

and the sign function $\operatorname{sgn}(t)$ is

$$ \operatorname{sgn}(t) \triangleq \begin{cases}
-1 \qquad & t<0 \\
\ \ 0 \qquad & t=0 \\
\ \ 1 \qquad & t>0 \\
\end{cases} $$

Because of the linearity of convolution and of the fact that the integral of a sum is the sum of integrals, we can think of this as the Hilbert transform of $\tfrac12$ added to the Hilbert transform of the sign function $\operatorname{sgn}(t)$.

The Hilbert transform of $\tfrac12$ or of any constant is zero because the two integrals expressing the principal value above will be exact negatives for **any** value of $\epsilon$ in the limit.  So the problem is just that of the Hilbert transform of $\tfrac12 \operatorname{sgn}(t)$.

In the integral above, let's say $t>0$.  The math will be identical with flipped signs for the case $t<0$.  For $t=0$ there will simply be the problem of infinity.

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{H}\Big\{ \tfrac12 \operatorname{sgn}(t) \Big\} & = \frac12 \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \left( \int\limits_{-1/\epsilon}^{-\epsilon} \frac{1}{\pi v} \ \operatorname{sgn}(t-v) \mathrm{d}v \ + \ \int\limits_{\epsilon}^{1/\epsilon} \frac{1}{\pi v} \ \operatorname{sgn}(t-v) \mathrm{d}v \right) \\
\\
 & = \frac{1}{2\pi} \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \left( \int\limits_{-1/\epsilon}^{-t} \frac{1}{v} (+1) \mathrm{d}v \ + \ \int\limits_{-t}^{-\epsilon} \frac{1}{v} (+1) \mathrm{d}v \ + \ \int\limits_{\epsilon}^{t} \frac{1}{v} (+1) \mathrm{d}v \ + \ \int\limits_{t}^{1/\epsilon} \frac{1}{v} (-1)  \mathrm{d}v \right) \\
\end{align}$$

Wow!  This is problematic.  The two integrals in the interior cancel each other, but the two integrals on the outside team up

$$\begin{align}
 \mathscr{H}\Big\{ \tfrac12 \operatorname{sgn}(t) \Big\} &= \frac{1}{2\pi} \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \left( \int\limits_{-1/\epsilon}^{-t} \frac{+1}{v}  \mathrm{d}v \ + \ \int\limits_{t}^{1/\epsilon} \frac{-1}{v}  \mathrm{d}v \right) \\
\\
 &= \frac{1}{2\pi} \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} 2\int\limits_{t}^{1/\epsilon} \frac{-1}{v}  \mathrm{d}v \\
\\
 &= \frac{1}{\pi} \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \ -\big(\log(1/\epsilon) - \log(t)\big)  \\
\\
 &= \frac{1}{\pi} \big( \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \  \log(\epsilon) + \log(t) \big) \\
\end{align}$$

I don't see how that converges to a finite value.

We'll have to get back to this in the future.  Meantime, suggestions and corrections from anyone are welcome.

Comment: I think the solution lies in the [regularized Hilbert transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform#Hilbert_transform_of_bounded_functions) for $L^{\infty}$ functions.

Comment: it's what the math.se guy said and pointed to exactly the same place you point to.  my feeling is to stay-the-hell-away from some of these functions that don't converge.

Comment: I did the math and it all works out! (with the regularized version of the Hilbert transform for bounded functions). Please check the second part of my answer.

Comment: well, i up arrowed you @MattL. but this *"new"* definition of the Hilbert transform is one that, to be honest, that i had never heard of before. $$ $$ i never claimed to know everything.